# Unable to disable notification vibration using checkbox(Android)

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications, push-notification, android-vibration

I am using Notification in MainActivity.class and i have checkbox in another Settings.class from where i want to enable or disable vibration on notification. Everything working fine but when i uncheck the checkbox vibrate still remain until refresh or restart the app. I don't want to refresh the activity or restart the app.

In main class :

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
            if(settingsAct.checkStatus1==1){
        notify.defaults |= notify.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    }
}
```

In Settings class :

```
if(mCheckVibrate.isChecked()){
        checkStatus1 = 1;
    }else{
        checkStatus1 = 0 ;
    }
```

Comment: use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to store and retrieve the values of CheckBox state.

Comment: ok i will try this but if any other solution

Comment: No, that's the simple and ideal solution for this problem.

Comment: No your solution is not working , i am getting status 0 and 1 exactly right just want to disable notification when checkStatus1=0 ... that is not working ....

Comment: Are you sure checkStatus1 is declared as `public static`?

Comment: Yes i am sure .. just problem is that if i enable vibration , its not going to disable until restart app or refresh activity

Comment: Are you doing something in oncreate or onresume  because of which you need to refresh or restart the activity.

Comment: you all are not understanding my question i think , i told just tell me if i am using notify.defaults |= notify.DEFAULT_VIBRATE; this for vibrating on notification then what i have to use for stoping vibrate or disabling vibrating without refreshing or restarting app thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have solved my problem i have changed from default notification vibration to following:

```
vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                        vibrator.vibrate(300);
```

For disabling vibration i have used :

```
vibrator.cancel();
```